# Change an element using ref (third-party library)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a third party library to display a table with pager :

```
<Grid 
    ref={Grid => {
      this.gridRef = Grid;
    }}
    {...props} />
```

I want to modify only the pager and create a new class `GridPager` to override it.

In my componentDidMount I can display the element of my Grid :

```
componentDidMount() {
  // display the Grid elements
  //console.log(this.gridRef.widgetInstance.element);

  // This won't work
  //this.gridRef.widgetInstance.element[0].childNodes[1] = <GridPager />; 

  // Change the Grid pager to simple 'test'
  // this.gridRef.widgetInstance.element[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = 'test'; 
}
```

I can add simple text using `innerHTML` but how to add a React class `GridPager` ?
This is my first time I use ref and working on DOM using React.

Answer (score 1):

By what I can tell what you are trying / want to do is both not possible or discouraged.

There should be no way of actively modify the React DOM like that.

`childNodes` elements should be read only even if you can still modify the inner HTML.

`ref`s should be used to trigger events across different Components of the React DOM when for some reason you don't want to use the props for passing funcions.

See more here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

and here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components

I see what and why you are trying to do this, but if you are using a component that you didn't create I don't think it's a good idea to try to modify it on the code that wraps or uses it and would instead make changes directly from the source.

Comment: The developers of this library (KnedoUI) provides an official way to change this using JQuery. I didn't use `ref` before anytime but in this scenario I think it's a real need. Thank you @Carlo :)